# Good Lower bound on the Beta function

Tags: inequality, gamma-function, integral-inequality, beta-function

Let $m>0$, $r>0$ and $0< k < m$ be three positive real numbers. I want to find a tight lower bound of the special case of the Beta function, which is given by
$$
B\left(\frac{m-k}{2}, \frac{r+k}{2}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m-k}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{r+k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+r}{2}\right)},
$$
where $\Gamma(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$ denotes the Gamma function.

Could someone share me some closely related references?

Comment: Did you use the bounds for the gamma function? Also, a lower bound is given by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196130/bound-on-the-beta-function

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for sharing the link. However, that inequlity holds only if  $\frac{m-k}{2} \geq 1$ and $\frac{r+k}{2} \geq 1$, which does not suit the conditions of this post. By the way,  the lower bound of that question should be $\max\{ \frac{1}{xy^x}, \frac{1}{yx^y}\}$.

Comment: Use $\Gamma(x + 1) = x\Gamma(x)$ to meet the conditions.